# Static variable redefinition with Visual C++

Tags: c++, static

I have 2 files each containing a static int variable which has the same name :

test-1.cpp:

```
#include "test-2.cpp"

static int a;

int main() {

}
```

test-2.cpp:

```
static int a;

void fonction() {

}
```

When I compile with `cl test-1.cpp` on command line, I get this error:

```
test-1.cpp(3): error C2086: 'int a' : redefinition
```

Comment: You included one file into another (it's as if you've copied its source). So now you've file with two `static int a` definitions, which your compiler promptly report to you as error. You probably wanted to compile two files separately, not to include one file into another.

Comment: Yes but I want to use the "fonction" function in test-1.cpp... I realized I have to use headers. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you *include* test2.cpp into test-1.cpp the actual code seen by the compiler is this:

```
static int a;

void fonction() {

}

static int a;

int main() {

}
```

Hence the redefinition.

The `#include` preprocessor command includes the file textually.

What you actually want is have both files test-1.cpp and test-2.cpp included into the Visual Studio project.

You want this:

test-1.cpp

```
#include "test-2.h"

static int a;

int main() {
  fonction();
}
```

test-2.cpp

```
#include "test-2.h"

static int a;

void fonction() {

}
```

test-2.h

```
void fonction();
```

Comment: Ok but I want to use the "fonction" function in test-1.cpp. Do I need to use a different name for the second static variable ?

Comment: You need header files. Editing the answer. All this can be read up in your C text book.

Comment: @daiSKeul ... and you can look up a good C++ book [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you are `#including` test-2.cpp in test-1.cpp. It's as if you have only one file. If you remove the `#include` and do this command

```
cl test-1.cpp test-2.cpp
```

then it will work.

This whole area is called *separate compilation* and it's something that newbies struggle with (it's also not often taught very well). Because of separate compilation you should **never** include one cpp file in another cpp file. Instead you should hand both files to the compiler so they can be compiled separately.

If one cpp file needs to know what's defined in another cpp file, then create a header file with declarations of what's in the second cpp file and include that in the first cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

In this line;

```
#include "test-2.cpp"
```

you tell the preprocessor to put the content of `test-2.cpp` into `test-1.cpp`. Hence you define `static int a;` twice. This is not allowed. To fix this, remove the `#include`.

Note that you need to carefully distinguish between declarations (which can occur many times) and definitions (which can occur only once). Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410563/9593596) for more info.

Comment: I still have to use ```#include``` but with a header file and not a cpp file... Thank you for your help and for the link !